# php Form and action in the same page

Tags: php, forms

I have a form like this

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="calc.php" method="post">
Primo numero:   <input type="text" name="a" /></br>
Operazione (+-*/): <input type="text" name="b" /></br>
Secondo numero:   <input type="text" name="c" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

lied to a separate .php file named calc.php

that is like

```
<?php echo $_POST["a"]; ?><?php echo $_POST["b"]; ?><?php echo $_POST["c"]; ?><strong>=</strong>
<?php 
    if ($_POST["b"] == "+")
   {
     echo   $_POST["a"] + $_POST["c"];


    }
    if ($_POST["b"] == "-")
    {
     echo   $_POST["a"] - $_POST["c"];
    }
    if ($_POST["b"] == "*")
    {
      echo  $_POST["a"] * $_POST["c"];
    }
    if ($_POST["b"] == "/")
    {
      echo   $_POST["a"] / $_POST["c"];
    }
?>
```

It works fine but I'd like to show the result in the same page

How can I do?

Comment: actually you can also leave the `action-attribute` blank or leave it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can put the code in the same file and change the form to:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

or

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```

to submit it to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @[ana-claudias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2656128/ana-claudia)'s answer i recommend using the htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS in case a client injects maliciuous characters into the url/variable.

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
```